# Can an ASP.NET 5 web application published in windows be run on linux?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I have a sample ASP.NET 5 web application created in Visual Studio 2015 using the default web application template.
I am targeting the dnx451 clr 1.0.0-beta5 (x64) and am able to successfully compile, publish and host this application on my windows box using kestrel web server.
I find that the published directory has a script file for windows(kestrel.cmd) and a bash script file.
My understanding is that in this case the published web application should also work as is, on a linux system provided the appropriate DNX runtimes are setup on the linux machine.
Is my understanding valid ?

Comment: As long as you compile with Mono, it should work on Linux and OS X too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: yes. It can run on Linux and OS X. See [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html) for Linux and [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html) for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no as long as you are not changing the target to dnxcore50. dnx451 will never be available on Mac or Linux since it is based on the full desktop .net framework